# Simplification of the calculation sum(value / row_number) in PostgreSQL without explicit row number assignment

Tags: postgresql, sum, aggregation

I'm working with a PostgreSQL database and I'm looking for a more efficient way to compute: `sum(value/row_number)`.

My current approach involves assigning row numbers in a separate step and then performing the summation, but this method requires grouping the data twice, which I'd like to avoid.

```sql
-- CREATE TEMP TABLE
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_data (
  value INT,
  group_id INT,
  created_at TIMESTAMP
);

-- PREPARE DUMMY DATA
INSERT INTO test_data VALUES 
  (20, 1, '2023-12-01'),
  (60, 1, '2023-12-02'),
  (5, 2, '2023-12-04'),
  (2, 2, '2023-12-05'),
  (9, 2, '2023-12-08'),
  (100, 3, '2023-12-04'),
  (50, 4, '2023-12-04'),
  (50, 4, '2023-12-07');

-- SELECT QUERY
WITH numbered_data AS (
    SELECT
        value,
        group_id,
        created_at,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY created_at) AS row_n
    FROM
        test_data
)
SELECT
    group_id,
    sum(value / row_n) AS my_result
FROM
    numbered_data
GROUP BY
    group_id;
```

I wonder if there is a possibility to perform this query in more simple step.

Unfortunately aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls so this is not working:

```sql
-- NOT WORKING
SELECT
    group_id,
    sum(value / ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at) )
FROM
    test_data
GROUP BY group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the query with the window function in a subquery. In this manner, the outer query executes the final summation aggregated by group_id, while the subquery computes the value / ROW_NUMBER() within the relevant window.

Try this updated version:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    SUM(my_result) AS final_result
FROM (

    SELECT
        group_id,
        value / ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY created_at) AS my_result
    FROM
        test_data
) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    group_id;
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: I have checked with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and it (almost) doesn't change the plan nor the performance.